# Target multiple td cells with jquery and change them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie to JavaScript and jQuery. I am trying to target table cells. I have this code working for me, but it only targets the first cell.

```
function hidestuff() {
    var thediv = $('#Chart4_div').find('.bdtablecell').eq(1);
    var text = thediv.text();
    text = text.replace(/\//g, '');
    thediv.text(text);
}
```

I tried this, but it didn't target all them and change it:

```
function hidestuff() {
    var thediv = $('#Chart4_div').find('.bdtablecell').eq(1).eq(4).eq(7).eq(10);
    var text = thediv.text();
    text = text.replace(/\//g, '');
    thediv.text(text);
}
```

How can I target each cell that I need too?

I also want to replace more than just the "/"symbol. I also want to change all instances of the "-" symbol to a space " ". How can I replace multiiple things?

Comment: We don't know which cells you have or need to target.

Comment: Seems like based on what you're selecting nth-child may help you out too: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: I tried to make a jsfiddle, but could not get it to work (I think because I have to pull stuff from an external location).
You can look at the source code on the test page here: http://goodandevilbook.com/test.html

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need the first, fourth, seventh and tenth, try this:

```
var thediv = $('#Chart4_div').find('.bdtablecell:eq(1), .bdtablecell:eq(4), .bdtablecell:eq(7), .bdtablecell:eq(10)')
```

This is using the selector :eq which works just like the function. By putting commas (,) between them in the find selector we are asking for any of the comma seperated list.

For a slightly cleaner look, you can try:

```
var thediv = $('#Chart4_div').find('.bdtablecell').find(':eq(1), :eq(4), :eq(7), :eq(10)')
```

Comment: Give me more information. Why didn't it look right? what happened? what was expected to happen?

Comment: Here is what it does: http://goodandevilbook.com/test2b.html 

I know its working, but it doesn't return it right somehow.

Comment: I want it to look like this, the other fellow's method worked.

http://goodandevilbook.com/test2.html

Answer (score 2):

`.eq()` method only returns one element and chaining it doesn't make sense. One option is using an array and the `.filter()` method.

```
var ind = [1, 4, 7, 10];

$('#Chart4_div').find('.bdtablecell').filter(function(i) {
    return $.inArray(i, ind) > -1;
}).text(function(_, currentText) {
    return currentText.replace('foo', 'bar');
});
```

Comment: This looks like it might work, but I am not sure how to implement it into my code. You can see the test page working here. I tried to make a jsfiddle, but could not get it to work (I think because I have to pull from an external location).
[link](http://goodandevilbook.com/test.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the html. Try this:

```
function hidestuff() {

    var thedivs = $('#Chart4_div').find('.itemsINeedToFind'); // new class, here!

    // iterate over each one cell
    thedivs.each(function() { 
        var $this = $(this);
        // replace every \ and - to a white space
        $this.text($this.text().replace(/[\s\-]+/g,' '));
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't really modify the html. (or at least I don't know how to....the table is generated by Google charts)